# \pushbuttons with Icons with pdflatex (xobject reference)

Tags: pdftex, forms, javascript

I would like to create a pushbutton with icons instead of text. Like the text in the example below the icons should change with the mouse options.

The manual of the eforms package (`eformman.pdf`) mentions options `\I`, `\RI` and `\IX`

```
  \I: (push buttons only) an indirect reference to a form XObject 
      defining the buttons’s normal icon
```

There is an example on http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/webeq_ex.html (eqforms.tex) but only for the dvips route. Is it possible to use icons with pdflatex too? And how do I create and reference the xobject? (I tried various variants with `\pdfxform` etc but to no avail).

(A solution which use javascript code would be fine too)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pushButton[\CA{Push}\AC{Me}\RC{Reset}\A{/S/ResetForm}]
    {myButton}{30bp}{15bp}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Due to the help of @AlexG I found out why the "natural" command \I, \XI and \RI didn't work: The relevant code in `eforms.sty` uses braces in the `/I` entry which imho doesn't work with `pdftex`. If I change the code everything works fine (I moved the `0 R` to the internal code):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newsavebox\imga
\newsavebox\imgb
\newsavebox\imgc
\sbox\imga{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\sbox\imgb{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\sbox\imgc{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
\immediate\pdfxform\imga
\edef\normalappearance{\the\pdflastxform}
\immediate\pdfxform\imgb
\edef\overappearance{\the\pdflastxform}
\immediate\pdfxform\imgc
\edef\downappearance{\the\pdflastxform}

\pdfcompresslevel0
\pdfobjcompresslevel0
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\@eqI#1{\ifx\annot@type\annot@type@button
    \def\eq@arg{#1}\ifx\eq@arg\@empty
    \let\eq@I\@empty\else\def\eq@I{/I #1\space 0 R}% removed brace around #1, 
                                                   % added \space 0 R 
    \eq@define@IconMK\fi\fi}

\def\@eqRI#1{\ifx\annot@type\annot@type@button
    \def\eq@arg{#1}\ifx\eq@arg\@empty
    \let\eq@RI\@empty\else\def\eq@RI{/RI #1\space 0 R}% removed brace around #1 ..
    \eq@define@IconMK\fi\fi}    

\def\@eqIX#1{\ifx\annot@type\annot@type@button
    \def\eq@arg{#1}\ifx\eq@arg\@empty
    \let\eq@IX\@empty\else\def\eq@IX{/IX #1\space 0 R}% removed brace around #1 ..
    \eq@define@IconMK\fi\fi}    
\makeatother

\pushButton[
  \TP{1}
  \I{\normalappearance}
  \RI{\overappearance}
  \IX{\downappearance}
]{myButton2}{100bp}{100bp}
\end{document}
```

### Edit 2

I have notified the author and he will change the code of `eforms.sty` so that `\I` etc works with pdflatex too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newsavebox\img

\sbox\img{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\immediate\pdfxform\img
\edef\normalappearance{\the\pdflastxform\space 0 R}

\sbox\img{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\immediate\pdfxform\img
\edef\overappearance{\the\pdflastxform\space 0 R}

\sbox\img{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
\immediate\pdfxform\img
\edef\downappearance{\the\pdflastxform\space 0 R}

\begin{document}

\pushButton[
  \mkIns{
      /TP 1 /IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>
      /I \normalappearance
      /RI \overappearance
      /IX \downappearance%
  }
  \A{/S/ResetForm}
]{myButton}{30bp}{22.5bp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. I would never had thought to use \AP (and I would have got the syntax right anyway). But the `\A{/S/ResetForm}` seems to be a bit dangerous: When I add a second button and then click on the first, then the first shows an empty frame and the second disappears. Can I add something to the buttons so that `Resetform` resets both to the "normalappearance" graphic?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I replaced the appearance dict (`/AP <<...>>`) with the appearance characteristics dict (`/MK <<...>>`). Maybe a better solution. Note that button names, here `myButton`, must be unique.

Comment: That works better (and the eform docu seems to be misleading, it says that about \MK "this key is available only for check boxes and radio buttons.". And I start to understand the connection between the commands and the pdf syntax. I think I will have to read a bit in the pdf reference.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Moreover, `eform`'s `\MK{...}` key doesn't seem to work as advertised. That is why I used `\rawPDF{...}` instead.

Comment: I looked up the code in eforms.tex. Instead of \MK you have to use `\mkIns{..}` in `\pushbutton`. And actually it looks as if \I{`\normalappearance}` should work too but I haven't yet find out why it doesn't ;-(.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. I actually tried `\mkIns{\I{\normalappearance}...}` but I couldn't get it work. So I resorted to `\rawPDF{...}` which is available, fortunately.

Comment: I don't think you can nest the commands so you have to use `\mkIns{/I ...}'

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Let me know if you can successfully make use of the keys provided by `eforms`.

Comment: I will expand my question when I have final solution. Now that I have a starting point I can dig in the code. Thanks!